# Writing simple javascript function and invoking it

Tags: javascript, php, twitter-bootstrap

I have bootstrap on my site and I want to use a different alertbox when I communicate with the users....

I only use this one: http://bootboxjs.com/documentation.html#bb-alert-dialog

It is defined like this (I always use the large one, and always title "rsite") and I only change the message. I have tried to write a funcion that takes userMessage as argument and outputs this but with no luck. Can you see what I do wrong?

```
 ReClamVersion = "0.4";

 DEFINE
 bootbox.alert({ 
 size: "large",
 title: ReClamversion,
 message: "Your message here…", 
 })

 My non working function
 function rAlert(userMessage)
 {
 return "bootbox.alert({ message:'" + userMessage + "',size: 'large',¨title:" + ReClamVersion+ '});'
 ;}
```

I try to invoke it by rAlert("hi") but it doesnt work. Where should I put my script so I can use it on all my pages? I use php and include my header.php. Should I put the script there?

Comment: what is ReClamVersion ? a js variable ?

Comment: yes, a variable

Comment: You're using a return statement not a function call, the code should be like this `function rAlert(userMessage){
 bootbox.alert({ message: userMessage, size: 'large', title: ReClamVersion});
}` also you're returning your code inside a string, unless you're gonna use `eval()` don't do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need quotes if you just want display the alert, using variables as parameters. Moreover the way you put the quotes is incorrect.
Try rewriting the function as follows

```
function rAlert(userMessage)
 {
 bootbox.alert({ message: userMessage ,size: 'large', title:  ReClamVersion });
 }
```

It's ok to put the function in the header.

Comment: Will this invoke it? <label class="btn btn-info btn-file" onclick="rAlert('Go'')" I have changed the code to your suggestion. Do I have to use these '' around the argument?

Comment: use <label class="btn btn-info btn-file" onclick="rAlert('Go');"> and be aware of quotes

Comment: THANK YOU IT WORKS! However it shows up two times :-(

Comment: maybe you call it 2 times :)

Comment: The script or the onclick?

Comment: I don't know. Simply maybe three's some jquery evetn handler somewhere..it's your code you should know